Suffix use in "materialality"?
My brain twitched when I heard materialality used to describe a home's architectural brutalist style formed with concrete.
Please enlighten me as to this use of the suffix ‑ality: is such use appropriate with material?

Where did you “hear” this term?

Are you sure you didn’t mishear material reality?

We saw it on a YouTube feature of "interesting" Architecture. A black concrete "Brutalist" style home. Thank you for the replies! And no, I heard the mistake correctly.  Hmmm things that make you twitch can be fun! Happy new year!

How sure can anyone be that 'materialality' was the term, here?

Arrant catachresis
Although instances of materialality (sic) can be found here and there on the internet, it does not occur anywhere in the Oxford English Dictionary, nor even in Google Ngram results. Like so many other such things on the uncurated internet, it should be considered a catachrestic use or deliberate marketing choice.
In fact, there are no words in English that end with ‑alality — and ‑ality isn’t even a suffix per se (see below).
The correct word is simply materiality, whose etymology the (paywalled) OED gives as:

Partly < material adj. + ‑ity suffix, and partly < material n. + ‑ity suffix, perhaps after post‑classical Latin materialitas material nature (9th cent.; from 13th cent. in British sources). Compare Middle French, French matérialité material quality (1470).

Strictly speaking, ‑ality isn't really a suffix, merely an ending. The OED says of the actual suffix ‑ity:

The termination was in Latin often added to another adjectival suffix, e.g.
‑āci‑, ‑āli‑, ‑āno‑, ‑āri‑, ‑ārio‑, ‑bili‑, ‑eo‑, ‑idi‑, ‑ido‑, ‑ili‑,
‑īli‑, ‑ino‑, ‑īno‑, ‑io‑, ‑īvo‑, ‑ōci‑, ‑ōso‑, ‑ui‑, ‑uo‑, etc., whence
the English endings ‑acity, ‑ality, ‑anity, ‑arity, ‑ariety, ‑bility,
‑eity, ‑idity, ‑ility, ‑inity, ‑iety, ‑ivity, ‑ocity, ‑osity, ‑uity, some
of which, as ‑bility (‑ability, ‑ibility) attain almost to the rank of
independent suffixes.

Many of the English words you can find that end in ‑ality were taken from some Latin where an adjectival ‑alis ending had joined with a nominal ‑itas ending to make some ‑alitas word, often in "Late" (post-Classical) Latin, which then ended up becoming an ‑ality word in English via French.
So these are likely just mistakes, just like so much you find on the uncurated internet.

catachrestic... or just more jargon.

Very worth keeping as analysis showing that assumptions about suspected affixes should be checked. Though OP should show research results, negative here in all probability.

Again, thank you for the replies!
